# How to make an AJAX call using lit-element/lit-html?

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit-html

I have started exploring the **lit-element** and wonder how to make an AJAX call to a REST API.

There is an element called **`iron-ajax`** but that is to be believed in the Polymer context.

Is there a way to do this in the **lit** without been imported from another context like Polymer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API. For this you can create one js module which exports function to make as AJAX call so that you can centralized all the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks Ruchita for the response. I was trying to know a native way of doing it in the lit context.

Comment: fetch api is the native way to do it in any context, including lit-element